# Gibbs sampler for local linear trend model

Tags: bayesian, sampling

**Question:** Consider the local linear trend model given by:
\begin{align*}
y_t = \mu_t + \tau \varepsilon_t \ \cdots \ \text{Observation equation} \\
\mu_{t+1} = \phi \mu_t + \eta_t \  \cdots \ \text{State equation}
\end{align*}
for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$, where $(\varepsilon_t, \eta_t)'$ is independent of $\mu_k$ for $k \le t$ and where:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_t \\ \eta_t \end{bmatrix} \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} N\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mu_1 \sim N\left(0, \frac{1}{1-\phi^2} \right)
\end{align*}

(Note everything is a scalar quantity in this question).

Consider a Bayesian analysis of this model under the prior distribution given by:
\begin{align*}
p(\theta) \propto \frac{1}{\tau}  \ \text{for} \ -\infty < \phi < \infty \ \text{and} \ 0<\tau<\infty
\end{align*}
where $\theta = (\phi, \tau)$.

Devise a Gibbs sampler to sample from the joint posterior distribution, $p(\mu_{1:T}, \theta \mid y_{1:T})$ where the notation $\mu_{1:T}$ denotes $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_T)$ and similarly, $y_{1:T}$ denotes $(y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_T)$.

---

**My Working So Far:**

The joint posterior distribution is given by:
\begin{align*}
 p(\mu_{1:T}, \theta \mid y_{1:T}) & \propto p(\mu_{1:T}, \theta, y_{1:T}) \\
 & = \underbrace{p(y_{1:T} \mid \mu_{1:T}, \theta)}_{\text{'likelihood'}}\underbrace{p(\mu_{1:T} \mid \theta)p(\theta)}_{\text{prior}} \\
&  = \left[\prod_{t=1}^{T} p(y_t \mid \mu_t, \theta)\right]\left[\prod_{t=1}^{T-1}p(\mu_{t+1} \mid \mu_t, \theta) \right]p(\mu_1 \mid \theta)p(\theta) \ \ \cdots \ \ (1)
\end{align*}
Since $y_t \mid \mu_t, \theta \sim N(\mu_t, \tau^2)$ for $t=1, 2, \cdots, T$, the pdf is given by:
\begin{gather*}
p(y_t \mid \mu_t, \theta) = \left(2\pi \tau^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\tau^2}\left(y_t - \mu_t\right)^2  \right]
\end{gather*}
Similarly, $\mu_{t+1} \mid \mu_t, \theta \sim N\left(\phi \mu_t, 1 \right)$, so the pdf is given by:
\begin{gather*}
p(\mu_{t+1} \mid \mu_t, \theta) = \left(2\pi\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu_{t+1} - \phi \mu_t \right)^2 \right]
\end{gather*}
We know that $\mu_1 \mid \theta \sim N\left(0, \frac{1}{1-\phi^2} \right)$, so the pdf is given by:
\begin{gather*}
p(\mu_1 \mid \theta) = \left(2\pi\left(\frac{1}{1-\phi^2} \right) \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{\mu_1^2}{2\left(\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}\right)} \right]
\end{gather*}
Finally, we are given that $p\left(\theta\right) \propto \frac{1}{\tau}$.

Substituting all of the above into Eqn. $(1)$, yields the joint posterior distribution:
\begin{align*}
p(\mu_{1:T}, \theta \mid y_{1:T}) & \propto \left[\prod_{t=1}^{T} \left(2\pi \tau^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\tau^2}\left(y_t - \mu_t\right)^2  \right]\right]\left[\prod_{t=1}^{T-1}\left(2\pi\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu_{t+1} - \phi \mu_t \right)^2 \right] \right] \\
& \times \left(2\pi\left(\frac{1}{1-\phi^2} \right) \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{\mu_1^2}{2\left(\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}\right)} \right] \left( \frac{1}{\tau}\right)
\end{align*}

I will implement a "blocked" Gibbs sampler sampling $\mu_{1:T}^{(i)}$ together, as follows:

For $i = 1, 2, \cdots, M$, sample:
\begin{align*}
\mu_{1:T}^{(i)} & \sim \mu_{1:T} \mid \phi^{(i-1)}, \tau^{(i-1)}, y_{1:T} \ \ \cdots \ \ (2)\\
\phi^{(i)} & \sim \phi \mid \mu_{1:T}^{(i)}, \tau^{(i-1)}, y_{1:T} \ \ \cdots \ \ (3) \\
\tau^{(i)} & \sim \tau \mid \mu_{1:T}^{(i)}, \phi^{(i)}, y_{1:T} \ \ \cdots \ \ (4)
\end{align*}

Sampling from $(2)$ is straightforward by using the Forward Filter Backwards Sampling [(FFBS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm)

**My Query:** I am stuck on how to sample from $(3)$ and $(4)$, in order to use a Gibbs sampler on $(3)$ and $(4)$, we need to find the full conditional of $\phi \mid \mu_{1:T}, \tau, y_{1:T}$ and $\tau \mid \mu_{1:T}, \phi, y_{1:T}$, but how do you find these full conditionals? I do not see any obvious way by examining the joint posterior distribution. Perhaps a Metropolis Hastings subchain could work? But then what should I pick for my candidate density for the $\phi$ and $\tau$?

Thanks in advance.